# Rails Rake Task - Delete records by passing model name and ids as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I am intending to write a generic rake task that allows me to destroy a model's records after taking in model name and ids as input params

```
  #lib/tasks/import.rake

  task :destroy_model_records, [:params] => :environment do |task, args|
    params = args.params.with_indifferent_access
    model = params[:model_name]
    ids = params[:ids]

    model.where(id: ids).destroy_all
  end
```

Here's what my params look like:

```
params = { ids:"[532]", model_name: Shop }
```

I've tried this but this does not return an error message and neither does it perform an operation, what am I missing here?

Comment: How do you pass parameters to the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load the model with `Object.const_get(model)` Then it will read the class on which the 'where' method should work. To verify the parameters, you can write them out using the `puts` method.

```
#lib/tasks/import.rake

task :destroy_model_records, [:model_name, :ids] => :environment do |t, params|
  puts params[:model_name]
  puts params[:ids]

  model = Object.const_get(params[:model_name])
  ids = params[:ids].split(" ")

  model.where(id: ids).destroy_all
end
```

And the task can be done like this:

```
rails import:destroy_model_records[Shop,'1 2 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a string as the `ids` parameter instead of an array. Your `params` should instead look like this:

```
params = { ids: [532], model_name: Shop }
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to split the array of strings and then map it to integers

```
ids = params[:ids].tr('[]', '').split(' ').map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Why not avoid the square brackets entirely? And comma-delimit the IDs?

Comment: Yes that's correct, that would be a neater solution!